# How to add different conditional statements in SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a column name 'Code' in my database and it contain different numbers like this..

```
Product      |      Code
===============================
  p1         |       0
  p2         |      120
  p3         |       0
  p4         |      222
  p5         |       1
  p6         |       1
  p7         |      180
  p18        |      300
```

I want to sort table, order by Code. Products with code '1' comes first, then all the numbers in ASC order, and at the end show Products with code '0'.  Like This

```
Product      |      Code
===============================
  p5         |       1
  p6         |       1
  p2         |      120
  p7         |      180
  p4         |      222
  p18        |      300
  p3         |       0
  p1         |       0
```

Any help for SQL query Thanks?

Comment: This suggests that *maybe* you should be using [`NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html) instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort on whether `Code = 0` (in ascending order, which is the default, false/0 comes before true/1); then sort on the value of `Code` itself:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY Code = 0, Code
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a742/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a trick with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT Product,Code FROM (
   SELECT Product,Code,0 AS ORD FROM Table1 WHERE code != 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT Product,Code,1 FROM Table1 WHERE code=0
) a
ORDER BY ORD,CODE
```

This will give you The != 0 first, ordered by code and then the =0.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8f118/12)</kbd>

Comment: @eggyal. You are right. Instead of deleting my answer, i wrote a way of ordering it the right way using almost the same approach, but i still like your approach better.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT product,code FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN Code=0 THEN (SELECT max(Code)+1 FROM table) ELSE Code END ASC;`